# Logo Moves All Over The Place When Resize Windows

Tags: css, header

Okay so I have a problem with a website I am working on.. infact I have this problem alot and never asked for help, I think it's time now. Here is my CSS:

```
    header {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    height: 50px;
    }
    .logo {
    background: url(logo.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 280px;
    }
```

When I resize my window the logo in the Header will go in to the right when the window is resized. I have tried position absolute, relative etc but it does the same thing. Any ideas please guys?

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>

<div class="logo"></div>

</header>
```

Here are links to pictures representing the problem:

This is where everything is working perfectly everything is alligned:

[FullSizedWindow http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212750/Full%20Sized%20Window.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212750/Full%20Sized%20Window.png)

and

This is where everything starts to go all over the place:

[WhenWindowIsRised http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212750/When%20window%20is%20resized.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6212750/When%20window%20is%20resized.png)

Any ideas? Please

Comment: Is it inside a floated element?

Comment: where do you want the logo to appear?

Comment: Not it is not inside a floated element, I havent added any floats. If you look at the  images I think you can tell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width on the header element. It's defaulting to `width: auto;` which is spanning 100% of the browser window. Thus, when you re-size the window's width, the header element is re-sized too moving the contents.

**Update 1**

You're using a margin to position the logo 280px from the left side of the browser window, so when you resize the window's width, your logo is moving too- the logo is being 'pushed'. What you want to do is wrap everything in a container div and set your margin spacing relative to that, not the browser window.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <header>

    <div class="logo"></div>

    </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {     
    background: #EEEEEE;    
} 
.logo {     
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/4hs7p.png) no-repeat top left;    
    width: 200px;     
    height: 198px;     
    margin: 0;    
}
```

**fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/ybe9d/2/

Comment: It didn't work man :/ the logo still gets pushed in it goes out of place

Comment: Thank you! But how do I still push my image in to where I wanted it, but when resixing it stays there! :/

Comment: The code I pasted works but for some reason the fiddle was messed up. Please look at the fiddle again and let me know if that still doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you :D Much appreciated! Been a great help I appreciate your time and effort man!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think to try off the top of my head would be to fully set the background properties.

```
background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Broken down that is:

```
background: url [left,right,px,%] [top,bottom,px,%] [repeat];
```

Can you post a JSFiddle so I can see it happen?

Comment: No man it didn't work yeah sure. http://jsfiddle.net/VAg8j/ The problem is when I resize the windows, the logo is perfectly aligned with the page it's when I make the windows smaller everything pushes itself in.. the logo does