# Logo jumping around when I resize screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m still new to html and css but I created a website and everything works just fine [image: working website] but when I resize the screen to a smaller width, the logo in my navbar starts jumping around. From 1300px to about 1200px it get´s pushed to the left side of the screen.
[image: logo pushed to left side]
Then it jumpes inwards. [image: logo jumped in] From there (1200 px - 760px) it get´s pushed to the left side again and jumps in again. [image: jumping logo again]
It does that a few times.

Under 760px, everything is fine. It looks as it should and nothing jumps around.

I would like the logo to stay on the left side of the navbar with a fixed margin-left.

It´s hard to explain but I hope you can help me anyway.

Html

```
     <body>
    <a name="top"></a> 
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand smoothScroll animated" href="#top">
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 150px;
  border: none !important;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
   background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
  height: 110px;
  width: 60px;
  transition: width 1s;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

I found this similar question [Logo Moves All Over The Place When Resize Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042420/logo-moves-all-over-the-place-when-resize-windows) but that changes nothing in my case.
I also tried to work with media queries and margin-left (with px and %) but nothing seems to help.

I could really use your help here. Thank you so much!

I forgot to mention I´m using bootstrap.

Comment: `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top` - Is this a Bootstrap site?

Comment: yes I used bootstrap. Sorry i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you remove any css that sets a  background image and place it into the navigation menu within your html with an img tag.

Done this a million times with bootstrap.

Comment: I tried it. The problem remains the same. :( The logo still jumps around.

Comment: Anyway you can get a version uploaded that we can visit to try it out in a browser?

Comment: Might be some type of media query doing that, but can't really tell until I see something better.